# Pandas: How to average rows with two columns having similar id's?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

| State Name | County Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Idaho | Ada | 20 |
| Idaho | Ada | 50 |
| Pennsylvania | Adams | 70 |
| Colorado | Adams | 25 |
| Pennsylvania | Adams | 21 |
| Illinois | Adams | 45 |
| Illinois | Madison | 45 |
| Illinois | Madison | 75 |

Then average the rows with **similar State and County name** such that the dataframe becomes this:

| State Name | County Name | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Idaho | Ada | 12.5 |
| Pennsylvania | Adams | 55.47 |
| Colorado | Adams | 47.2 |
| Illinois | Adams | 19.5 |
| Illinois | Madison | 75.14 |

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Why the mean of Idaho is 12.5?

Comment: There are multiple similar rows of different dates. I just added a dummy value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['State Name','County Name']).mean()
```